# Extended socket information from ss

Tags: linux, networking, sockets

Running the following command gives me extended socket information.

```
$ss -tuen
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                       Peer Address:Port   
tcp   CLOSE-WAIT 1      0                                                  ::1:51826                                               ::1:ipp      ino:19094 sk:00000002 -->
```

If i understand correctly, the ino:19094 is the inode number of the socket. What does the following mean?

```
sk:00000002 -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the output is due to the `-e` option. From the `man ss` you can see that:

> -e, --extended
>
> ```
> Show detailed socket information. The output format is:
>   uid:<uid_number> ino:<inode_number> sk:<cookie>
>   <uid_number>
>     the user id the socket belongs to
>   <inode_number>
>     the socket's inode number in VFS
>   <cookie>
>     an uuid of the socket
> ```

So this means that its a universally unique identifier (uuid) of the socket.

Comment: But it's far too short to look like an UUID, and honestly this is the first time I've even heard of Linux sockets _having_ UUIDs. How is it actually assigned? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: You're right that it's too short to be a UUID, but since that's what the manual page says, I guess it's at least some sort of an ID. Considering its length it's probably per system(kernel) unique id and is most probably used as a shorter way to address the socket for some sort of socket control (instead of the inode number or the two pairs of ip:port). After all that's what IDs are usually used for.

Comment: which linux system did you use to get this? my ubuntu man page does not have any format description...

Comment: @drdot Kubuntu 18.10